# KnockoutJS - Submitting a form to the server

Tags: knockout.js

If I use Knockout to render a form that will accept customer input data that needs be posted back to the server what is the recommended way of doing this.

Do I go the traditional route of having the form submit to the server? If I do this I have to give unique names to all the form elements. How do I do this in Knockout?

Or do I send the view model back to the server via an Ajax call and if it succeeds then redirect using window.location.replace(...).

Answer (score 2):

Either way is fine, it depends on your needs.

Having the form submit to the server works well in many cases as it's simple.

If you want to do some preprocessing, performing an AJAX call is probably the route to take.

To answer you sub-question in the middle - how to set the `name` attributes with Knockout - use the `attr` data-bind like:

```
<input data-bind="value: firstname, attr: { name: 'firstName' }" />
```